# Dynamic programming - Gold mine grid optimization TLE

Tags: c++, recursion, grid, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm trying to solve Gold Mine problem from https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/gold-mine-problem2608/1/#. I am receiving TLE for the following code. I have looked at the solution also yet dont understand what minor mistake I made that the code received TLE and the solution code.

```
class Solution{
public:
    
    int helper(int a , int b, int n , int m , vector<vector<int>> M, vector<vector<int>> &N){
        if(a<0 || b<0 || a>=n){
            return INT_MIN ;
        }
        if(N[a][b]!=-1){
            return N[a][b];
        }
        if(b==m){
            N[a][b] = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            N[a][b] = M[a][b] + max( (helper(a+1,b+1,n,m,M,N)) , max(helper(a-1,b+1,n,m,M,N),helper(a,b+1,n,m,M,N)));
            return N[a][b] ;
        }
        // return N[a][b];
        
        
    }
    int maxGold(int n, int m, vector<vector<int>> M)
    {
        // code here
        vector<vector<int>> N(n,vector<int>(m+1,-1) );
        int ans = 0 ;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            // int ans2 = helper(i,0,n,m,M,N);
            // if(ans2>ans){
            //     ans = ans2;
            // }
            ans = max(ans,helper(i,0,n,m,M,N));
        }
        return ans;
        // just one extra in right to store 0s 
        // position a,b to a,b
        // n,m to n-1,m-1
    }
};
```

The solution given on the site :

```
// C++ program to solve Gold Mine problem
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int collectGold(vector<vector<int>> gold, int x, int y, int n, int m, vector<vector<int>> &dp) {
 
    // Base condition.
    if ((x < 0) || (x == n) || (y == m)) { 
        return 0;
    }
   
    if(dp[x][y] != -1){
        return dp[x][y] ;
    }
 
    // Right upper diagonal
    int rightUpperDiagonal = collectGold(gold, x - 1, y + 1, n, m, dp);
 
     // right
    int right = collectGold(gold, x, y + 1, n, m, dp);
 
    // Lower right diagonal
    int rightLowerDiagonal = collectGold(gold, x + 1, y + 1, n, m, dp); 
 
    // Return the maximum and store the value
    return dp[x][y] = gold[x][y] + max(max(rightUpperDiagonal, rightLowerDiagonal), right); 
}
 
int getMaxGold(vector<vector<int>> gold, int n, int m)
{
    int maxGold = 0;
    // Initialize the dp vector
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n, vector<int>(m, -1)) ;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 
        // Recursive function call for  ith row.
        int goldCollected = collectGold(gold, i, 0, n, m, dp); 
        maxGold = max(maxGold, goldCollected);
    }
 
    return maxGold;
}
```

I suppose that calculating all 3 directions differently and then taking max seems to make the actual solution faster, but would like to understand the reason for the same to improve myself.
EDIT1 - Nope, still received TLE after calculating differently for all 3 directions, although it did manage to do more test cases which I dont understand why.

Comment: `int helper(int a , int b, int n , int m , vector<vector<int>> M, vector<vector<int>> &N)` will copy everything in `M` at every call. That's a lot of copies for a 2D `vector`.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and fix the garbage "solution" found at that site so that it follows best C++ practices.  Things like passing vectors by value and usage of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- this is why sites such as the one you visited should not be used as C++ learning material.

Comment: is there any alternative to copying the array ? I could get around by making global variables but it would be a bad practice